# curl command cannot be work using shell script to call it dynamically by getting user input

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to have a curl command like below

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://abcd.com/api/v4/projects/<projectId>/triggers' \
--header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>' \
--form 'description="my description"'
```

Now I wrote a shell script function to generate it dynamically

it need projectId, token, and description as a pramter

```
callApi(){
while IFS="," read -r -a users; do
for u in "${users[@]}"
do
url="'https://abcd.com/api/v4/projects/$1/triggers'"
echo $url

header="'PRIVATE-TOKEN: $2'"
echo $header

desc="'description=$u token'"
echo $desc

tk=$(curl --location --request POST $url \
--header $header \
--form $desc)

echo $tk

done
done <<< $(cat $3)
}


callApi "<projectId>" "<token>" ./users.csv
```

It echo perfectly
But
It thorws error

Comment: You have many errors .. Run your script through `https://www.shellcheck.net`. Basically, remove your single quotes to allow variable expansion and place your options into an array `url=("https://abcd.com/api/v4/projects/$1/triggers")`

Comment: @rr0ss0rr: Look again. The single quotes are *inside double quotes* — I doubt that they’re the problem.

Comment: (1) Please don’t post questions that say “It throws error”.  Include any error messages you get in your question.  For that matter, don’t say “It echo perfectly”.  *Show* what it echos.  (2) You should always quote variables when you use them; e.g., ``POST "$url" --header "$header" --form "$desc"``.

Comment: But rr0ss0rr may be partly right: try taking out the single quotes.

Comment: on the other hand, tk= doesn't use any quote around variables... but uses variables that now include single quote around their data which is probably bad because these single quotes will be sent on the wire (and if there's a space in a token... even worse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the accepted answer at [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

> The reason you face those problems is word splitting and the fact that quotes expanded from variables don't act as quotes, but are just ordinary characters.

I usually follow the below format when building a curl command, assigning each piece into an array

```
    url_request=("https://abcd.com/api/v4/projects/$1/triggers")
    url_body=(--form "$desac")
    url_header=(--header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $2")
    url+=("${url_request[@]}" "${url_body[@]}" "${url_header[@]}")

    response=$(curl -s "${url[@]}")
```